# background-image won't appear when used in combination with ajax and url rewrite rules

Tags: css, ajax, url-rewriting, background-image

I have the following site layout. Main page is being loaded using url rewriting rules (apache) eh. www.page.com/section/information. There is a right hand side panel on this page. Content of that panel is being loaded with ajax in and contains few divs with background-image style set on it. Problem is, that background image is not being displayed

Now, if I use standard string url (www.page.com/?action=section&title=information), that background-image appears. It also appears when inserted as  (using / as a prefix to indicate absolute path), even when rewritten url is used

So now I'm puzzled cause I basically can't see way out

Comment: Please show some code. What way do you define the background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use absolute image paths or put this into your header

```
<base href="http://www.page.com/" />
```

Comment: Brilliant. Putting <base> at the beggining of ajax-loaded content helps. It was actually enough to put <base href="/" /> there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think in src attribute you have relative path of image try with absolute path of image.

Comment: I tried various combinations... relative, absolute (also tried 'dotting' a folder back). <base> tag proposed buy shivenz helped tho